# Dynamic component imported stuck in loading phase : next js

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, dynamic-import, react-player

I am new to next js. In my project I need to display youtube videos. I have an api which provides me the video ids to show with its meta details. I wanted to create dynamic pages for each videos. I am using react-player as player.

Here is my code

[videoId].tsx

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Layout from '../../components/layout';
import { IVideoItem } from '../../models/videos.model';
import VideoContainer from '../../components/videos-page/video-container';
import { getVideosPaths, getVideosPageTitle, getVideosPageDescription, getVideosData  } from '../../services/videos-page.services';

export default function VideoPage({videoInfo} :IVideosPageProp) {
    const router = useRouter()

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  return(
    <>
        <Head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <title>{getVideosPageTitle(videoInfo)}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={getVideosPageDescription(videoInfo)} />
            <meta property="og:title" content={getVideosPageTitle(videoInfo)} key="ogtitle" />
            <meta property="og:description" content={getVideosPageDescription(videoInfo)} key="ogdesc" />

        </Head>
        <VideoContainer data={videoInfo} />
    </>
  )
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = await getVideosPaths()
    //console.log('paths: ',paths);
    return {
      paths,
      fallback: false
    }
  }

  export async function getStaticProps({ params }:IVideosPageStaticProp) {
    const {videoId} = params;
    const videoInfo = await getVideosData(videoId)
    return {
      props: {
        videoInfo
      }
    }
  }

interface IVideosPageProp {
    videoInfo: IVideoItem
}

interface IVideosPageStaticPropParams {
    videoId: string
}

interface IVideosPageStaticProp {
    params: IVideosPageStaticPropParams
}
```

video-container.tsx

```
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { IVideoItem } from '../../models/videos.model';
import styles from './videos-container.module.scss';
import VideoTag from '../home/videos-block/video-tag';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faEye, faThumbsUp, faThumbsDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import moment from 'moment';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ReactPlayer = dynamic(
    () => import('react-player'),
    { loading: () => <p>...</p>, ssr: false }
)
  

export default function VideoContainer({data} :IVideosPageProp){
    const videoInfo:IVideoItem = data;
    const videoTag = [{"tagName": "Foo", "tagId": 1}]
    const fallBackElement = () => {
        return <img src={videoInfo.default_thumbnail_url} width="100%"/>
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles['videos-container']}>
            <ReactPlayer
                url={`https://youtu.be/${data.video_id}`}
                controls
                width = "100%"
                light={true}
                playing={true}
                fallback={fallBackElement()}
                config={{
                    youtube: {
                      playerVars: { showinfo: 1 }
                    }
                }}
            />
            <div className={styles['videos-body']}>
                <div className={styles['tag-list-container']}>
                    {videoTag.map((tag, index) =>{
                        return <VideoTag videoTag={tag} key={index}/>
                    })}
                </div>
                <div className={styles['video-title']}>
                    {videoInfo.title}
                </div>
                <Row className={styles['video-numbers']}>
                    <Col md={2} xs={2}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} className={styles['views-icon']} />{videoInfo.views_count}</Col>
                    <Col md={2} xs={4}>{moment(new Date(videoInfo.published_at)).format('Do MMMM YYYY')}</Col>
                    <Col md={4} xs={2}></Col>
                    <Col md={2} xs={2}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsUp} className={styles['views-icon']} />{videoInfo.like_count}</Col>
                    <Col md={2} xs={2}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsDown} className={styles['views-icon']} />{videoInfo.dislike_count}</Col>
                </Row>
                <div className={styles['video-description']}>
                    {videoInfo.description}
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

interface IVideosPageProp {
    data:IVideoItem
}
```

When I run `yarn dev` the page is loading properly and the video player is rendering and working as expected. But when I run `next buld` and after that `next start`, the page is loading, but player is not loading. Insted it shows the "Loading..." message on the page, I refreshed several times, no luck. Not able to understand the issue. Can any one help?

Update 1:
The page is rendering with video title, video description etc. But the dynamically imported video player is not rendered. At the place of video player, it shows 'Loading...'.

Comment: You need to return `fallback: true` from `getStaticPaths`, to display a fallback page and have it updated when data is available.

Comment: @PsyGik, Ok, Thanks. But that doesn't solve my problem. Page is loading for me, except video, title, description everything coming correctly.

Comment: Your question mentions that it shows "Loading..." message on the page. As per your code, "Loading..." is a fallback state and not the actual page. So the question here is, is the page loading in fallback mode, or the actual content is rendered?

Comment: @PsyGik, Page is rendering, but in the place of video player, it shows 'Loading..'. So the dynamically imported react player not rendered. Rest of the contents are rendered and displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can dynamically load from the node_module, like this:

```
const ReactPlayer = dynamic(
    () => import('react-player'),
    { loading: () => <p>...</p>, ssr: false }
)
```

But you should be able to do this by creating a `react-player` component first, then dynamic import it like this:

```
// create a component named Player.js
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

const Player = props => (<ReactPlayer {...props}/>)
export default Player;

// then dynamic import it:
const Player = dynamic(
    () => import('../components/Player'),
    { ssr: false }
  )

// Then use <Player> with the same props
```

Comment: I tried your approach. But same result. Player is not rendering. It shows the 3 dots(...), at the place of the player.  Dev server working fine, but when I run the page using next start after build, it is not working.

Comment: Can you post some steps on how to reproduce this? I created a next sandbox and added ReactPlayer to it, and everything works fine (both in dev and when running the built version).

Comment: Inspired by you, I too created a separate application and did POC for react player with dynamic import(The code in question is just a part of whole project). To my surprise, it worked.  After some debugging and trial and error, I found that there was some other module which was causing error. Sorry for the inconvinience. I am marking your answer as accepted. Thank you for the support.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the root cause? So that if anyone faces the same problem, they have a reference. Thank you

Comment: I am quite not sure what is the actual issue. I was using react bootstrap navbar in the same page. I had an import for bootstrap.css file also in the same page. As part of trial and error, I commented one by one and found that bootstrap css import and navbar was causing the issue. I don't know why. Later I moved those to _app.tsx file, it worked. Seems weird for me.